# Function input only recognized when defined in working environment

Tags: r, dplyr

I am writing a function that automates fitting a model and storing results. However, I am confused by why the dependent variable (dv) cannot be found by the function unless it is defined in the working environment. I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

```
library(bartMachine)
df <- data.frame(
  x=rnorm(100, 2,1),
  x2=rnorm(100, 3,1),
  y=rnorm(100, 1,0.5),
  y2=rnorm(100, 1,0.6)
)

iv <- df %>% select(x, x2) %>% names()

model_function <- function(data_clean, iv, dv, nit) {
  
  dat <- data_clean %>% select(all_of(iv), all_of(dv)) %>% drop_na()
  print(names(dat))
  print(dv)
  n <- nrow(dat)
  
  out <<- tibble(run = 1:nit) %>%
    mutate(
      data = map(run, ~sample_n(dat %>% select(all_of(iv), all_of(dv)), size = n, replace = T) %>% drop_na()), # unweighted
      mdl = purrr::map(data, ~bartMachine(X=as.data.frame(.x) %>% select(all_of(iv)),
                                          y=as.data.frame(.x) %>% select(all_of(dv)) %>% unlist(), seed = 999,
                                          num_rand_samps_in_library=10000,
                                          num_iterations_after_burn_in = 1000)))
}
```

Fails

```
model_function(data_clean=df, iv=iv, dv="y", nit=2) # works
model_function(data_clean=df, iv=iv, dv="y2", nit=2) 
[1] "x"  "x2" "y2"
[1] "y2"
bartMachine initializing with 50 trees...
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `mdl = purrr::map(...)`.
Caused by error in `all_of()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `y` doesn't exist.
```

Works

```
dv="y"
model_function(data_clean=df, iv=iv, dv="y", nit=2)
dv="y2"
model_function(data_clean=df, iv=iv, dv="y2", nit=2)
```

Comment: Why are you using `<<-` ? Is using `return(out)` an option?

Comment: what are you referring to with `data_clean`? Is it an old name for `df`, your example data, that you forgot to change?

Comment: @uke 1) to inspect the output. 2) to remind myself to bring in cleaned data.